# Is there an electronic device that stays "on" until the current through the device reaches a certain level?

Tags: components, semiconductors, component-selection

I have the vague recollection that a device like this exists. The device is gated on, after which it approximates a short circuit, until the current through the device rises to a set level, at which point the device turns itself off until the next gate signal. Am I making this up, or does such a thing exist?

Comment: For the current into the other direction it sounds like a triac

Comment: Thyristor (conduction in one direction only) or triac (can conduct in both directions). But both turn off *below* a ceratin current level, you seem to imply that you want it to turn off *above* a certain level? Maybe add a polyfuse in series.

Comment: A poly fuse? (re-settable fuse)  (but there is no gate signal.)

Comment: Sounds like a useful device .I had to resort to discrete components to do this .Relays would be too slow and wear out .My question about Veb didnt yeild anything for me in this endevour.

Answer (score 1):

Your description since to be a closed match to a [silicon controlled rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_controlled_rectifier) which can be triggered via a gate (it also has alternative methods to be triggered) and basically latches on, until the current drops until a level where the latch cannot longer be sustained and then turns off.

Comment: I've clarified that my question is looking for a component that turns off when the current rises to a set level, not when it falls to a set level. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

How about a humble DPDT relay!

Connect like this...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ4tWX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As long as input current generated by ***SOURCE*** is low enough, the relay looks like a short (less of course the resistance and inductance of the coil).

When current gets high enough to pull relay, the the current source sees an open circuit until the ***GATE*** reset button is pushed.

NB: Only suitable for application where the cycle time is less than 1Hz! :)

Answer (score 0):

The closest devices I can think of would be [thyristors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thyristor) or [TRIACs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC).

Both have a gate terminal that enables the switch. Once the gate signal is on, current may flow through the device. The switch turns off once the voltage / current drops below a threshold.

So it doesn't exactly match your description of turning off at a set level, but I thought I'd mention these devices anyways.

Comment: I've clarified that my question is looking for a component that turns off when the current rises to a set level, not when it falls to a set level. Sorry for the confusion.